# Java oneliner to convert String into HashSet<Character>

Tags: java, java-8

I can propose few answers myself, but they are **very far** from being elegant.

Prove me that Java is not that hopeless. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8+, you might use a `forEach` and something like

```
String str = "Hello";
Set<Character> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
str.chars().forEach(e -> set.add((char) e));
System.out.println(set);
```

which outputs

```
[H, e, l, o]
```

Comment: Does not seem like a oneliner to me...

Comment: It has two advantages over other suggestions, it works and it's easy to understand. Reducing code to one line serves what practical purpose?

Comment: Ability to use it in static member initializer.

Comment: You should prefer the collect approach (which a one-liner btw), than the for-each one. It suffices that someone turns the stream in parallel so that you run into concurrency issues.

Comment: I think, if you decide to use a tool (like streams), you should do it the intended way. Using `forEach` to mutate an existing collection should be the last resort, if the existing operations don’t work. This is not appopriate here as there is a canonical solution: `str.chars().mapToObj(i->(char)i).collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Comment: If you want to control the type of the `Set`, using a custom collector becomes more concise:  `.chars().collect(LinkedHashSet::new, (s,i)->s.add((char)i), Set::addAll)`